# How to Triforce on /b/ on ubuntu

Tags: unicode, ascii

How can you type three triangles in the shape of a triangle? So a ascii art of the [Triforce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triforce) from Zelda using the triangle symbol.

/b/ is a image board on 4chan. Text on this image board is edited by an automatic system which removes all preleading spaces. This makes ascii art quite difficult to achieve. There is a trick to it using a special space char. The alt code to get this space char in windows is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 255 and the alt code to get the triangle in windows is <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 30.

What are the keyboard shortcuts to get these symbols on Ubuntu and how can I get them to work on 4chan?

Comment: What is a triforce? What do you mean by /b/? There are plenty of triangle-shaped characters, which one do you mean? You can look up the Unicode code point on [Shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/) if you don't know it.

Comment: I think now it was clear.

Answer (score 10):

To get a triangle, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>, then type `25b2`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

To get the space, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>, then type `a0`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Edit: To answer the comment below:

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>, then type `a0`, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>, then type `a0`, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>, then type `25b2`, then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>, then type `25b2`, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>, then type `a0`, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>u</kbd>, then type `25b2`

You'll get something like this

```
 ▲
▲ ▲
```

---

Alternatively you can enable compose keys to create these symbols with ease without remembering these annoying keyboard number-letter combinations.

Open GEdit and insert the following:

```
include "/usr/share/X11/locale/en_US.UTF-8/Compose"

<Multi_key>     <t>     <r>     <i> : "▲"   U25B2   # Triangle
```

Save this as .XCompose (case sensitive) in your home directory.

Open your keyboard settings (system settings → keyboard settings) and go to the shortcuts tab.
Under the "typing" section you'll find a "Compose Key" setting. Set this to your compose key (I advice right alt)

[image: Compose Key setting]

Log out and log back in.
For the non-breaking space press <kbd>Compose Key</kbd> → <kbd>space</kbd> → <kbd>space</kbd>.
For the triangle char press <kbd>Compose Key</kbd> → <kbd>t</kbd> → <kbd>r</kbd> → <kbd>i</kbd>

[If it isn't working](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/207025/add-custom-compose-key-sequence-not-working) add

```
export GTK_IM_MODULE="xim"
```

to the end of ~/.profile.
If xim isn't working for you you'll have have to install uim (`sudo apt-get install uim`) and replace the xim in ~/.profile with uim.

Congratulations you are now triforcing like a pro.

Comment: I knew that, but if you try that on /b/ you get the typical newfag triforce http://www.theultimateshowdown.net/images/NEWFAGS-CANT-TRIFORCE.jpg , what do you have to do to make a proper triforce?

Comment: answering the edit, on youtube it works, but on 4chan it doesn't. I don't know what type of sorcery is behind this

Comment: you have to use another space on 4chan. I've reflected this in the new edit

Comment: which is the code for that?

Comment: ctrl + shift + ua0

Comment: I used to have a shell script for doing this. Ill look into it.

Comment: If you're using it a lot you can enable compose keys and add the ▲ symbol to the compose key list (the non-breaking space is already in the compose key list with shortcut Alt->space->space)