# What is the propper way to triforce on 4chan in ubuntu?

Tags: unicode, unicode-entry

How do you triforce on 4chan in ubuntu???
The regular ctrl+shift+ua0 or u00a0 dont work as invisible characters on 4chan. On windows i would use alt+0195 if i remember correctly, but i cant figure out how to do it on ubuntu. Many thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Triforce on /b/ on ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/393119/how-to-triforce-on-b-on-ubuntu)

Comment: i have already looked on that page, didnt help or answer my question. ctrl+shift+u+a0 does not work as an invisible char or a non breaking space

Comment: if you read closely, you will see that you have to use ctrl+shift+u+a0 *twice* on the top row. I guess it doesn't work the first time but does when you use it once more for a second time as one invisible char.

Answer (score 1):

▲
▲ ▲

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>u</kbd> `a0` seems to work fine for me.

Comment: it works here on the askubuntu website,tried it on 4chan and its a no go